# Parsing Pipe separated Strings

Tags: java, string, parsing, pipe

I am using the following code to parse a string:package org.datacontract;

```
public class TestParsing {


    public static void main(String[] args){
        String test = "6000FCI|6|22|122548";

        String[] result = test.split("\\|");

        for(String s : result){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

*My output is:*

```
6000FCI
6
22
122548
```

How do I get the first value only where my output be : 
6000FCI

Comment: `String result = test.split("\\|")[0];` ?

Comment: Just get the first value in the array? `String myString = result[0];`

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the first value and your input is so simple, do not need a regular expression but do something more simple:

```
test.substring(0, test.indexOf('|'));
```

This can be processed more efficiently. Otherwise, you would just access the value at the first index of your result array.

*Note*: If it is possible that `test` does not contain a pipe, rather do this:

```
int index = test.indexOf('|');
String result = index == -1 ? test : test.substring(0, index);
```

Comment: Only work if you have at least one `|` in the original string.

Comment: Yes, but since the input is hard coded I assume that the OP wants to know how to extract this information from a given input.